# Multiple affiliations in ACM conference template

Tags: acm, author-number, author, affiliation, acmart

The first author has multiple affiliations that are different in everything including country. The second author also has diffirent affiliation than the first author's two affiliations.

How should I go about it? I suggest to make the three affiliations at the button in a shared way and just add superscript on the names of the authors. So the first author will have superscript (1,2) and the second (3). I think this is more convenience as there is a possibility for a third author to join which shares the affiliation with one of the authors.

This is my current script which I do not know how to make my above description on it (make the affiliations shared with a number proceeding them, and superscript above the author names).

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\author{First Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{First University}
  \city{City}
  \state{Country}
}
\email{mail@mail.com}

\author{Second Author}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Second University}
  \city{City}
  \state{Country}
}
\email{mail2@mail.com}
\begin{abstract}
Abstract here.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

I need to do something like the following (numbers as superscript on the authors names) and the affiliations are shared in the line below their names.
[image]

Comment: Related: I'm not sure if this is helpful or perhaps even a duplicate: [Multiple authors with different primary affiliation, but same additional affiliation](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/381530)

Comment: @Alan Munn Thanks but the solution provided is not what I'm looking for. I do not prefer footnote-like way to specify the affiliations.

Comment: But this is how the ACM class is set up, so I'm assuming that's what they require.

Comment: @Alan Munn please see my edit. This picture is taken from ACM publication and I want to do the affiliations similar to it.